# Test Dynamics CRM 2011 OnPremise with SoapUI - 'Script is disabled' response

Tags: soap, dynamics-crm-2011, soapui

thanks to all for reading about this.

I'm testing **Dynamics CRM 2011** Endpoint with **SOAP**, and after configuring a test suite with SOAPUi the response from the request is coming back as web page that reads: "Script is disabled. Click Submit to continue."
It' seems that both authentication and request is correct and I tried to change different parameters in SOAPUi following experiences from other users but anything had worked for me.

It's a SOAPUi misconfiguration? Or it came from the service Endpoint?

I've also checked this article from Technet: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1425.ad-fs-2-0-script-is-disabled-click-submit-to-continue.aspx

I'm calling a Dynamics CRM 2011 On Premise SOAP Endpoint

**SOAPUi Test Request**

Headers:

- SOAPAction `http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts/Services/IOrganizationService/Retrieve`
- Accept `application/xml, text/xml, */*`
- Content-Type `text/xml; charset=utf-8`

Request URL: `http://myserver/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc/web`

Authentication: NTLM (with user, password and domain)

Request:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:ser="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts/Services" xmlns:con="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts" xmlns:arr="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
   <soap:Header/>
   <soap:Body>
         <ser:entityName>contact</ser:entityName>
         <ser:id>91A6E0D1-1182-E511-B589-5EF3FC563A99</ser:id>
         <ser:columnSet>
            <con:AllColumns>false</con:AllColumns>
            <con:Columns>
               <arr:string>fullname</arr:string>
            </con:Columns>
         </ser:columnSet>
      </ser:Retrieve>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Response: (I've cleared some private information)

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Working...</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <form method="POST" name="hiddenform" action="http://myserver:444/">
         <input type="hidden" name="wa" value="wsignin1.0"/>
         <input type="hidden" name="wresult" value="*here was my security token*"/>
         <input type="hidden" name="wctx" value="rm=1&amp;id=40167dd3-3ac9-4961-a476-3b7ada5a6395&amp;ru=%2fmyorganization%2fXRMServices%2f2011%2fOrganization.svc%2fweb"/>
         <noscript>
            <p>Script is disabled. Click Submit to continue.</p>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
         </noscript>
      </form>
      <script language="javascript">window.setTimeout('document.forms[0].submit()', 0);</script>
   </body>
</html>
```